# Why does my php command in CLI return empty line?

Tags: php, command-line, command-line-interface

When I'm writing a php -f program.php command in my CLI, i get no response.

I have tried to write php -h command or php -r 'echo 'try' command  or php -i command and I still get no response.

Enviroment variables is properly set but problem occurs even if I'm in xampp/php/ directory.

Php in my applications works, problems occurs only in CLI.

Problem starts probably after my windows update. Anyone can help me please?

Comment: What is the output of php -v ? What do you mean by "I get no response" ? Do you have no output at all, or do you have any error or anything ? Could you try :  php -r 'echo "foo bar";'

Comment: What command line do you use ? Is it windows' cmd.exe ?

Comment: i add an answer becouse of image which i cant upload in comment.